# remove all styles based on browser version

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer-7, cross-browser

I would like to know how i can remove all css styles based on checking if the browser is less than IE8.

So if it detects IE7 then remove all styles? I wonder if this is possible via some jquery?

**Will this fix most IE7 issues:**

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<script src="http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version/2.1(beta4)/IE7.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: What you put in there checks if the IE version is _less than_ 7, in other words, IE6 or below. You probably meant `[if lte IE 7]` or `[if lt IE 8]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
    <body class='oldIE'>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if gte IE 8]>
    <body class='ok'>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]>
    <body class='ok'>
<![endif]-->
```

here you would need to prefix all the styles you don't IE7 to apply with `.ok`

another method would be

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
    //include an old IE specific stylesheet or none at all
<![endif]-->
<!--[if gte IE 8]>
    //include your stylesheets
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]>
    //include your stylesheets
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: i ended up using if lt IE8 and then setting some javascript to fire to redirect to a splash page saying IE7 or < sucks. Frankly speaking anyone who uses IE7 should not be aloud to view my content.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you want to remove all styles for a browser version. I suppose that you have some CSS problems with IE7, and often a good way of fixing it, rather than deleting all your CSS, is to use ie7.js: http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/.

Here is a [demo](http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/test/index.html) of what it can do.

Also, this script has a version for IE8 and IE9.

Comment: do i just paste it in the header?

Comment: ie7.js doesn't remove any CSS like you asked. It just tries to make IE7 behave the same way as other versions/browsers...

Comment: jamie, IE7.js did nothing for my page. The only way i can check it is compatability mode.

Comment: @Jamie. Yes, I know. I should have been clear that I do not attempt to answer the question, rather, this provides an alternative instead removing all styles.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to remove a specific **class name** rather than wiping the entire CSS for an element:

```
// Identity browser and browser version

if($.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version) == 7) {

   // Remove class name
   $('.class').removeClass('class');

   // Or unset each CSS selectively
   $('.class').css({
      'background-color': '',
      'font-weight': ''
   });

}
```

Comment: is this even feasible because i have like 5 styles on UL.tiles for example. I basically want to make the page like when the Internet first start. Or just redirect them to a page saying, IE7 sucks.

Comment: "unsetting css" with `.css` (which edits inline styles) does nothing if there is stylesheet rules. Also, not all css rules are class based.